# how to use security features in Zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, crypt

Are there specific examples of the use of cryptographic tools from Zend \ Crypt? Examples are used Zend \ Crypt in modules? On the official site says only the basic use of these properties. For example when I want to record and encrypt the data (not the password) to the database. I have not yet found any tutorial. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find some example on following sources.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.crypt.public-key.html
http://static.zend.com/topics/Cryptography-made-easy-with-ZF2.pdf
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.crypt.block-cipher.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html